# What is a void() prvalue and how is it used?

Tags: c++, casting, void

Reading cppreference's description of [functional style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), I stumbled upon the following explanation for `void()`:

> If target-type is (possibly cv-qualified) void, the expression is a void prvalue without a result object (since C++17)

Now I understand that I can create a `void()` prvalue like so, but what can I use it for and why is this even possible?

Comment: Please note that `void(some_expression)` and `void()` are two different things. The first is the kind of function-like explicit conversion ("function cast") that you ask about. But `void()` is a type, it's the type of a function taking no arguments and that doesn't return anything.

Comment: As for why casting to `void` might be useful, it could be because you enable extra warnings that will emit a warning for not using the result of an expression, and you want zero warnings in your build. Then cast the result to `void`. That's of the top of my head, there might be other reasons as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `void()` can also be an expression, depending on the context.

Comment: your quote is incomplete and appears more than once on the linked site. Please provide more context

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you refer to this paragraph

> 2. The functional-style cast expression consists of a simple type specifier or a typedef specifier (in other words, a single-word type name, that is, cases such as `unsigned int(expression)` and `int*(expression)` are not valid), followed by a comma-separated list of expressions in parentheses.

and the bullet

> - If there's no expression in parentheses: if target-type names a non-array complete object type, this expression is a prvalue of type target-type, designating a temporary (until C++17)whose result object is (possibly with added cv-qualifiers) (since C++17) of that type. If target-type is an object type, the object is value-initialized. If target-type is (possibly cv-qualified) `void`, the expression is a void prvalue without a result object (since C++17).

If you put the standardese language aside, its actually not that complicated. I suppose you wonder why one would write something like this:

```
void bar() {
    return void();
}
```

According to the above this is valid, but not really useful. Now consider you have a function template like this:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo() {
    return typename T::value_type();
}
```

Then you can instantiate it with a `T` whose `value_type` is `void`:

```
struct X{
    using value_type = void;
};
int main() {
    foo<X>();
}
```

There is no object returned, but the type of the expression `T::value_type` in `foo<X>` is `void`, the function has `void` return type.

Answer (score 3):

> but what can I use it for

There are several places where it is useful and directly used:

- SFINAE with `decltype` (superseed by `requires` in C++20)

  ```
  template <typename T>
  auto print_foo(const T& value)
  -> decltype(foo(t), void()) // SFINAE on foo(t), but return void
  {
      std::cout << foo(t);
  }
  ```
- split expression to handle evil `operator,` (if one side is `void`, there are no custom available `operator,` usable).

  ```
  template <Typename F, typename...Ts>
  void for_each_call(F f, const Ts&... args)
  {
      ((f(args), void()), ...);
  }
  ```

There is also after substitution in generic code:

```
template <typename T>
T foo()
{
    return T();
}
```

`foo<void>()` is valid.